# How do I deal with a question that keeps on going?

Tags: discussion, comments

A few weeks ago I came across [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/30609/similarity-between-a-heart-attack-and-a-spasm/30612?noredirect=1#comment52338_30612). It was pretty interesting to me and I figured it was one that I could handle answering. In the beginning, I had some communication with the asker, simply because I wasn't sure I understood the question. I edited it to make it clearer and then proceeded to answer. So on and so forth...

Anyhow, the person accepted my answer and left a comment, which I responded to to the best of my ability. This pattern continued and has continued up until today (and I'm sure today wasn't the last time I'll hear from the asker).

The person is continuing to ask questions within the comments; which I personally have no problem with... However, it appears to me like they have been asking the same question every way they can think of. So I have provided short, tidbits of information back; answering them as best I can. They also un-accepted my answer. I was a bit miffed. I understand that maybe they did it because I hadn't updated my official answer to match what I wrote in the comments. I did let them know that I do have every intention of editing my answer - as you can see, I haven't yet though, I'm busy and have life going on. So, my problem is, this question got out of my I'm-comfortable-with-handling-this realm long ago and I've been doing Google searches and flying by the seat of my pants trying to answer these questions. The only reason I'm remaining involved in the conversation is that no one else ever *got* involved and I don't want to to leave the asker dangling.

So! My question is, where do I go from here? I'm thinking about responding to the person asking the question and giving them contact information to someone who could perhaps give them better information, like Johns Hopkins or The Mayo Clinic.

Comment: If this happens, ask the person to either edit their question or to open a new one.

Comment: @Chris Okay. I shall see what I can do. I may have to let it sit for a few days so that the steam coming out of my ears doesn't show on screen XD

Comment: Related: [Chameleon questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things you can do:

1. If you felt you have adequately addressed the question, move on,
2. If you feel the additional questions in the comment are more appropriate for a second question, tell the OP that they should be asking a new question linking to this one, and
3. If the OP doesn't understand the answer no matter what you do, it may be in your best interest to let it rest; otherwise, this cycle will continue.

You could say that seems mean to do, but don't you have better things to do or potentially more people to help? If you stay involved in a question that appears to have no end, you will reach less people on all SE networks.  Then there is option four.

4. Double check your answer. Maybe it needs improvement, and if you can't improve it, but it may be helpful leave it or delete it if it offers no value.

The OP has only a finite window to unaccept your answer. After that window, it takes an added answer or and edit to your answer in order for this action to occur. Moreover, it is entirely the OP option to accept or not accept. Don't let it worry you which action they take since if your answer can stand on its on merits, up votes will follow and surely make up for the unaccept.

Comment: Thanks :) I guess it just bothered me that they un accepted and I lost reputation over it.

Comment: @L.B. Sure but the upvotes to your answer still mean that you have 40 more rep than you would have done if you didn't answer.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yeah, that is _nice_! :)